# How to know if an order is from existing customer or new customer?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
    $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
        ->getLastRealOrderId();

    $orderId = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->loadByIncrementId($lastOrderId)
        ->getEntityId();

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    echo $order;
    $udo = array();
    $udo['CID'] = '123';
    $udo['TYPE'] = '123';
```

but I need to assign a different value to TYPE, if the order is from an existing customer or from a new one.

any idea>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can diff new customer by created time of order:

```
$LastOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$LastOrdertime= $LastOrder->getCreatedAt();

$OrderCollection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$LastOrder->getData('customer_email'))
            ->setOrder('created_at','asc');
$fstoredetime= $OrderCollection->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt();    

if($fstoredetime==$LastOrdertime):
// new customer
else:
//old customer
endif;
```

Comment: so this code gets the customer, with the customer gets the first order? if both the first order and the current order are at the same time, its a new customer. if not an existing customer.

Comment: yes.. right....

Comment: Voting -1 because it's bad approach. Do no recommend to hang on created_at date.

Comment: I used this approach, but instead, like @zhartaunik said, I sorted the collection the same way - and then getFirstItem()->getId(), and compare that to the current orderId. Works fine, without the messyness of dealing with dates.

Answer (score 3):

In following event call:

> Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
```

We have two entities which have customer_id value. When we have existing customer - then `$order->getCustomerId()` will return **it's real ID**. If customer is just created - then it returns **true**.

So if you like to apply something to order based on customer (is new/old) run in observer:

```
if ($observer->getOrder()->getCustomerId() === true) {
    //here goes code for customer, which was just created
} elseif ($observer->getOrder()->getCustomerId() > 0) {
    //here goes code for old customer
} elseif ($observer->getOrder()->getCustomerId() === null) {
    //here goes code for guest
}
```

## Explanation:

> Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder

```
/**
 * Create order based on checkout type. Create customer if necessary.
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
 */
public function saveOrder()
{
    $this->validate();
    $isNewCustomer = false;
    switch ($this->getCheckoutMethod()) {
        case self::METHOD_GUEST:
            $this->_prepareGuestQuote();
            break;
        case self::METHOD_REGISTER:
            $this->_prepareNewCustomerQuote();
            $isNewCustomer = true;
            break;
        default:
            $this->_prepareCustomerQuote();
            break;
    }
```

Let's have a look at three protected methods: _prepareGuestQuote(), _prepareNewCustomerQuote(), _prepareCustomerQuote()

```
/**
 * Prepare quote for guest checkout order submit
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
 */
protected function _prepareGuestQuote()
{
    $quote = $this->getQuote();
    $quote->setCustomerId(null)
```

As you can see guest customer has **null** value

---

```
/**
 * Prepare quote for customer registration and customer order submit
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
 */
protected function _prepareNewCustomerQuote()
{
    ...
    $quote->setCustomer($customer)
        ->setCustomerId(true);
}
```

For new customer we are setting **true**

---

```
/**
 * Prepare quote for customer order submit
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
 */
protected function _prepareCustomerQuote()
{
    $quote      = $this->getQuote();
    $billing    = $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $shipping   = $quote->isVirtual() ? null : $quote->getShippingAddress();

    $customer = $this->getCustomerSession()->getCustomer();
    ...
    $quote->setCustomer($customer);
}
```

For existing customer we are taking it's object from session. As you understand - this object will have customer_id value.

Answer (score 1):

$order->getCustomerId() should return zero for guest if I remember right.

Comment: ya.Amasty ,you are right, so  i am using customer_email

Comment: /**
     * Prepare quote for guest checkout order submit
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
     */
    protected function _prepareGuestQuote()
    {
        $quote = $this->getQuote();
        $quote->setCustomerId(null)